# How to create a swipeable carousel in Monodroid?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Can some tell me how to go about creating a carousel that can detect swipes. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Apparently I have to use something called ViewPager. I also used the component Android support library v4. Following is the link to the tutorial that I followed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBmBKivPVX4&list=UU1qaJiVMUz0zP_NgfXKZCpw

Comment: Hey that is my video, hopefully you have already found out how to use the ViewPager. Otherwise please go ahead and edit your opening posts with specifics on what you don't understand and I will try my best to answer them :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the video. I already created what I want based on the video. So you have already helped me :)

Comment: THANK YOU!! Been trying to find this exact functionality for way too long!!